# Confusion over global variables and how to use them

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsreport

I think I'm a little confused as to how global variables work in nodejs. I have this code:

```
var jsreport = require('jsreport-core')()
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
// make sure to pass the path to your `helper.js`
var helpers = fs.readFileSync(path.join('/Development/jsreport-new/data/templates/Sample report', 'helpers.js'), 'utf8');

var data = fs.readFileSync(path.join('/Development/jsreport-new', 'scratch.json').toString(), 'utf8');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
jsreport.init().then(function () {
    return jsreport.render({
        template: {
            scripts: [{
                content: "request.data={endpoints: json }; done();"
            }],
            content: fs.readFileSync(path.join('/Development/jsreport-new/data/templates/Sample report', 'content.handlebars'), 'utf8'),
            helpers: helpers,
            engine: 'handlebars',
            recipe: 'phantom-pdf',
            phantom: {
                "orientation": "portrait",
                "format": "A3",    
                "margin": "3cm",
                "headerHeight": "3cm"
            },
        },
        data: {
            "books": [
                {"name": "A Tale of Two Cities", "author": "Charles Dickens", "sales": 351},
                {"name": "The Lord of the Rings", "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien", "sales": 125},
                {"name": "The Da Vinci Code", "author": "Dan Brown", "sales": 255},
                {"name": "The Hobbit", "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien", "sales": 99},
                {"name": "Carlskii", "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien", "sales": 99}
            ]
        }
    }).then(function(resp) {
        //prints pdf with headline Hello world
        console.log(resp.content.toString())
        resp.result.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('helloworld4.pdf'));
        setTimeout(function() {
            process.exit();
        }, 3000)
    });
}).catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e)
});
```

I need to pass the json data that read from a local file to a jsreport template. i.e. It needs to be passed to the content within the template `content: "request.data={endpoints: json }; done();"`

However, I just get `[Error: json is not defined]`.

I then tried defining the json variable as global variable. e.g. `global.json = JSON.parse(data);`, however it makes now difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `json` variable here isn't actually global. It's local to your node module's scope, and no other modules will be able to access it.

This means, by the time your report parses and executes `"request.data={endpoints: json }; done();"` from within its own scope, it isn't aware of `json`.

To answer your question about when to use global variables, the slightly snarky but valid answer is "never." Managing data accessibility is always recommended. Instead, I recommend you include the json data in the context value directly, like so:

```
scripts: [{
    content: "request.data={endpoints: " + JSON.stringify(json) + " }; done();"
}]
```

Comment: add quotes around `JSON.stringify(json)`.

Comment: Thanks very much for this and the detailed explanation as to what was going wrong. So I guess the bit I still don't get is why the json variable is available to `JSON.stringify` ?

Comment: Happy to help! The `json` variable is available here because it's being executed in your own module's context before the `scripts` array is given to JsReport. Notice the value of the `content` property you're providing is a string that happens to be code, and not a function. This questionable requirement by the creators of JsReport is why this code needs to run detached from its closure. By serializing your variable into a string and concatenating it into the report script _before_ we pass it to JsReport, we can send the data while still playing by JsReport's unusual rules.

Comment: Put another way, if we refer to the `json` variable in the script string it won't work because that variable won't exist when it runs, but if we take the _value_ of the variable and put it in the script, it works.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used node.js but based on your results

> [Error: json is not defined].

I am led to believe the problem relates to the following

```
var data = fs.readFileSync(path.join('/Development/jsreport-new', 'scratch.json').toString(), 'utf8');
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

json is not given a value because data fails to declare, or at least, not declare properly.

I suggest you write the value of data to the console, then figure it out from there.

```
console.log(data);
```